# Very slow tensorflow model prediction for variable sized 1D data

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing a binary classification problem for variable sized 1D data.

My problem is with the model prediction speed.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import random
```

##### Dummy inputs and their corresponding outputs  ...

(*not my actual data, just for illustration purposes*)

```
train_inputs = np.array([np.random.randint(0,10,random.randint(10,15)) for i in range(100)])
train_labels = np.array([[np.mean(i)] for i in inputs])
```

and my tensorflow model...

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
input_img = Input(shape=(None, 1))
x         = Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', padding='valid')(input_img)
y1        = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
y2        = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
z         = Concatenate(axis=1)([y1,y2])
output    = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(z)
model     = Model(input_img, output)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Training ... a generator function that converts the variable sized arrays into a list of lists, to address the variable size issue  (inspired from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920)).

```
def generator(inputs, labels):
    i = 0
    while True:
        inputs_batch = np.expand_dims([inputs[i%len(inputs)]], axis=2)
        labels_batch = np.array([labels[i%len(inputs)]])
        yield inputs_batch, labels_batch
        i+=1

model.fit(generator(train_inputs, train_labels),
    validation_data=generator(valid_inputs, valid_labels),
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_inputs),
    validation_steps=len(valid_inputs), epochs=2)
```

##### Prediction

.. thousands of test samples, all with very different sizes, bigger than training data sizes. How to predict them all in one go? 
  Or at least significantly speed up the process, instead of doing `model.predict(...)` one by one? 
`multiprocessing` / `multithreading` / `ragged tensor` suggestions from previous `stackoverflow` questions have not worked.

Below is the code I wrote, which is basically just as slow as a `for` loop:

```
test_inputs = np.array([np.random.randint(10,150,random.randint(15,150)) for i in range(5000)])

def generator_predict(inputs):
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        inputs_batch = np.expand_dims([inputs[i%len(inputs)]], axis=2)
        yield inputs_batch

results = np.around(model.predict(generator_predict(test_inputs)))
```

This is annoyingly slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share your gist so that It can be reproduced and we can check what's happening ?